# Only 2 steps are different when compared to two feature files. (cucumber-selenium-java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, cucumber-java

I am learning cucumber. I have two scenarios. I can't say the exact due to company policies. First Step file is like

```
Scenario 1: Flow with attachments
Given Login to APP
When User chooses "country"
And clicks "Yes"
And attaches "files"
And Go to location page
And add comments
Then Submit

Scenario2: Flow without attachments
Given Login to APP
When User chooses "country"
And clicks "Yes"
And add players manually
And User picks players
And User clicks on a player
And does the settings
And Go to location page
And add comments
Then Submit
```

Do I need to write all the steps again in Scenario 2 or can I do something so that I can bypass writing all the steps in feature file.
I mean can I maintain only different steps in the 2nd feature while like we do in writing step file or glue code for that.
If yes how to do it, so that it run all the previous steps. Please help

Comment: NO. There is not any way to do this ( At-least not that I am aware). Also it a total no no w.r.t. to Cucumber. As a good practice two scenarios should be as independent to each other as possible. Please have read at below: https://automationpanda.com/2017/01/30/bdd-101-writing-good-gherkin/

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the `Background` keyword. https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background

Comment: Background - ... but my intention was about post steps too ..
@rahulrai: thanks for the link. I follow the same as said

Comment: Ah Background- but they have no relevance in your case as background in something which will execute before start or every scenarios in feature file . You are talking about steps which could be anywhere in scenarios. I hope you are clear on this now. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing all the steps in terms of small actions the users performs on the system (like "go to page", "click this" , "submit that"), think about what the user is trying to achieve and create a step that describes that in a way that is **meaningful to the user** (i.e. "add players from a file", or "add players manually"). The step definition for that step will then contain all of these actions on the system (click this, fill that, etc). You can also use what we call "helper methods" from your step definition; for example create a method that will navigate to a certain page, and call that method with the relevant page to go to from your various step definitions.

That way your scenarios will describe the intended behaviour of the system, or what the user is supposed to be allowed to do (or not do).

Also, from the examples you've provided it is not clear to me what it is you are testing/asserting. I've always found it helpful to use "Given/And" to set up the original state of the system, "When/And" for the actions to be performed that you want to test the outcome of, and "Then/And" to verify the expected result.
The title of the scenario should clearly describe what it is the scenario tests for.

From your example, I've assumed that you are testing that a user is able to add players either from a file or manually. In that case, the scenarios could look something like the following:

```
Scenario: User is able to add players from a file
Given a user who is logged in
And the user has selected "country"
When the user attaches "files"
And adds a comment about location
Then the players are added
And the comment is saved

Scenario: user is able to add players manually
Given a user who is logged in
And the user has selected "country"
When the user adds players manually
And adds a comment about location
Then the players are added
And the comment is saved
```

In the example above, I am also assuming that the following steps:

```
And add players manually
And User picks players
And User clicks on a player
And does the settings
```

are actually all (always) needed to add players manually, so all of those actions would be performed in the one step "And add players manually" (either by implementing them all in one step, or calling several helper methods from that one step).

By describing the behaviour like this it is much clearer what you are testing in each scenario and what the expected behaviour of the system is.

Also, it will lead to way **less duplication** of "steps" (as was your original question, I believe).

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge shared. Yes, I do agree this. Thanks for letting me know more about behavior driven tests

Comment: You're welcome. You can find some more info here: https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/bdd/ and join one of the Cucumber support channels (i.e. Slack) if you have more questions :)